# How can i insert multiple values together in a list

Tags: c#, list

instead of adding values by each line I wants to add in a single line..Is there any method?[image: 1]

Comment: Did you even try *anything*? Googling for example: add multiple elements at once into loop.

Comment: AddRange(new string[] {"1","2","3"});

Comment: Write an extension method that takes a parameter array.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/524128/c-adding-multiple-elements-to-a-list-on-one-line.html

Comment: @HimBromBeere I tried to search...But I got more complicated solutions like writing function for inserting

Comment: @AccessDenied Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
 someStringsList.AddRange(new string[] { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" });
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Use collection initializers in case that you creating a collection.

```
List<int> digits = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Or you can push multiple values to already created collection with AddRange method.

```
digits.AddRange(new List<int>() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
```

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use an extension method:

```
    public static void Add<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
            list.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **AddRange**

someStringsList.AddRange(*YourListOfStrings*)